# Regular Expression matching syntax

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I need to replace every instance of any text in square brackets with something else, with each square bracket block being treated separately.  For example, start with:

`[quote author=joe link=topic=765.msg4476#msg4476 date=1330380346] This is the quoted text [/quote] This is the new post`

being turned into:

`** This is the quoted text ** This is the new post`

I tried using the following:

```
preg_replace('/\[.*\]/', '**', $msgtext);
```

What I get is:

`** This is the new post`

It seems to be matching from the first '[' character to the last ']' character in the entire string, even if there are a bunch of separate blocks of square brackets in the larger text.  How do I change my regex to replace each block between the square brackets individually?  Obviously my .* in the regex is matching everything including right brackets until the last one, but I want it to stop at the first right bracket it encounters, and then repeat that logic throughout the entire string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a *non-greedy* match, either by using the `/U` flag to make the whole pattern greedy:

```
preg_replace('/\[.*\]/U', '**', $msgtext);
```

or by using `.*?` ("zero or more, and preferably as few as possible") instead of `.*` ("zero or more, and preferably as many as possible"):

```
preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', '**', $msgtext);
```

Alternatively, you can use `[^\]]` ("any character except `]`") instead of `.` ("any character except newline"):

```
preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/', '**', $msgtext);
```

Comment: Thanks, guys, all of the above worked like a charm.  I used the any character except version, but the non greedy would have worked as well and gotten the same result.  Solved.

Comment: @BenCahan you should accept the answer (by clicking the check mark below the votes) if you believe it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

By default, PHP's regexp do greedy matching, you need to set this to ungreedy (e.g. by using the u switch)

```
preg_replace('/\[.*\]/U', '**', $msgtext);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
preg_replace('/\[[^\]]*\]/', '**', $msgtext);
```

Comment: oops! just after posting saw ruakh 3rd answer is same. I vote for that